# Skype4py doesn't respond to group chats

Tags: python, skype, skype4py

I tried running a script to respond to individual and group chats, but it only responds to individual chats

```
import Skype4Py

def commands(Message, Status):
    if Status == 'SENT' or Status == 'RECEIVED': 
        if Message.Body == "ping":
            cmd_ping(Message)
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass

def cmd_ping(Message):
    Message.Chat.SendMessage('pong')
    print "Ping Command Received \n"

skype = Skype4Py.Skype(); 
skype.OnMessageStatus = commands
skype.Attach();

while True: 
raw_input('')
```

Comment: `'RECIEVED'` -> `'RECEIVED'`?

Comment: made a spelling error while changing some stuff, it still doesn't work on group chats though.

Comment: Ah, ok. I've never worked with Skype4py but that was something I noticed. Either way, did you check if `OnMessageStatus` is actually being called during a group chat? Say, by logging to the console or by always replying?

Comment: I read through the documentation and this was the only call i could find that checks for new messages

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you have created chat in new version of Skype.

Please try the following solution: create P2P chat (via `/createmoderatedchat` in any group or personal chat). We had the same issue in our project, so you can refer to our [wiki page](https://github.com/Sicness/levitan/wiki/Creating-Chat-For-Levitan).